# Ruby: How do you configure an enum in a fixture?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, enums, fixtures

Given this class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

enum permission: {
    permission_user: 1,
    permission_staff: 2,
    permission_manager: 3,
    permission_admin: 4,
    permission_super_admin: 5
}
```

I want to create a fixture that looks like this:

```
testuser1:
  id: 1
  username: sam
  permission: :permission_staff
```

I've tried a number of variations of syntax, but haven't found something that works. the resulting user.permission is either nil or 0. I know that enum is relatively recent addition. Can this be done?

Comment: perhaps try something like: `User.permissions[:permission_staff]` ? (note: I'm totally guessing, but if it's an enumerable... it should be accessible as an enumerable)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [enum docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) you can refer to the enumerable through the class like this:

```
User.permissions[:permission_staff]
```

And the factories are just ruby code - so they should be able to access the value in the same way

```
testuser1:
  id: 1
  username: sam
  permission:  <%= User.permissions[:permission_staff] %>
```

Comment: seems logical, but it doesn't work. All of the permission values are set to zero regardless of which symbol is used in the brackets

Comment: sorry, that should be erbified. Fixed

Comment: thanks. that works. never put it together that yml is processed like an erb file

Comment: Note that this only works when the enum in the model defines the value. If they are dynamically defined eg `enum permission: [ :permission_user, :permission_staff, ...]` then the fixture cannot get the value.

Comment: Note the plural in User.permissions[:permission_staff]. I spent sometime to get this right

Comment: Note that the comment by bpruitt-goddard above is not correct, at least not in Rails 5.